# unhashable type: 'list' error with my project

Tags: python, hash

i was traying to make a percentage calculator program with python , by this way :

```
students = {'mohamed':(60,80,90),
           'omar':(50,77,69),
           'ahmed':(88,66,87),
           'ali':(888,69,54)}

names = list(students.keys())

def percentage_calc(a,b,c):
   per = (a + b + c / 300 )*100
   return per

mm = {}

for name in names:
   a , b ,c = students[names]
   mm[names] = percentage_calc(a, b, c)


for name , result in sorted(mm.items()):
   print('the result of {} is {:3.2f} %'.foramt(name,result))
```

but i got that error :

[image: error :]

how can I fix it ? , thanks.

Comment: I think you meant to write `students[name]` instead of `students[names]`. Also `mm[name]` instead of `mm[names]` probably.

Comment: `sorted((sum(v) / len(v), k) for k, v in students.items())`?

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 mistakes in your code:

- 1: `students[name]` instead of `students[names]`
- 2: `mm[name]` instead of `mm[names]`
- 3: `{your_code}.format(name,result))`  instead of `{your_code}.foramt(name,result))`

Comment: you're right ,  the names of variables confused me , thank you .